# calling a command from a parent view model with relativesources

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, binding

I have a window that allows the user to edit some information. Upon saving, the information gets saved in a database. The parent window that displays the information, gets the information from aforementioned database. However on the child window close, the information should update. The best way that I can figure to do this, is to call a method from the parent window's viewmodel (the method that originally populate the information). The best way that I found to do this is through `RelativeSource FindAncestor` in the view's command bindings. 
However, after setting a breakpoint, i have determined that the method evoked by the delegate command is never triggered.

```
  <Button x:Name="closeButton" Content="Close" 
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                    VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                    Width="75" 
                    Margin="403,270,0,-46" 
                    Click="CloseWindows" 
                    Command="{Binding DataContext.MouseDownCommand, 
                              RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
                              AncestorType={x:Type local:MainWindow}}}"/>
```

command in parent viewmodel:

```
MakeSelection = new DelegateCommand(OnSelectionMade);
```

method where the breakpoint is set:

```
private void OnSelectionMade()
{
     ShowDropDown = false;
     CarrierList.Clear();
     NodeTokenList = BackUpNodeTokenList; //reset list
     _populateCarrierListWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
     _populateCarrierListWorker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(PopulateCarrierList);
     _populateCarrierListWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler
           (PopulateCarrierCompleted);
     _populateCarrierListWorker.RunWorkerAsync(_node);
     ShowCarrierList = true;

}
```

Comment: A parent window is not a visual ancestor of a child window so you cannot use a RelativeSource to bind to another window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on an `MVVM` framework that you use, you can use an `EventAggregator` implementation, like `PubSubEvent` for `Prism` or `Messenger` for `MVVM Light`. Basically, a child viewmodel sends/publishes a notification upon its command execution, and the parent viewmodel subscribes to such notification and executes its own notification handler method.